# Connect two networks by WAN port, not vpn

Tags: networking, router, routing, wan

I got a job in a big company as IT manager.

Because some problems in the past they had, I want to separate each sector with a different network.
But I want to each computer from specific network see another computer of another specific one.

Heres the setup:
https://postimg.cc/YvLKpMdq

The LAN IP of the routers 1 and 2 are: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1. I could ping the WAN IP but not the LAN IP of the routers. So I created a static route in the main router, and now I can ping and access them by the internal IP.

But still can't ping the computer or the access the computer from a network to another.

I tried to do a static router in the others routers too but without sucess...the routers are Mercusys MR50G and TP LINK ARCHER C54. I don't want to have VPN, and I want this setup to make each sector with your own network and DHCP.

Comment: Why not just use LAN ports on your two routers and make your life very much simpler.  You can eliminate the switch underneath the ISP router.

Comment: Also make sure you are managing tasks with your Server, Accounts, AD and Distribution groups.  This also will be much simpler in the long run.

Comment: What’s the point of separating two networks if the PCs can continue to talk to each other? I think you should take a step back and re-plan the network without NAT but with firewall rules. Also keep in mind that link-level discovery mechanisms will not work across routers by default.

Comment: Those don't look like "big company network" routers... But exactly _what kind_ of static routes have you tried to use? Have you checked whether the _firewalls_ of those routers allow packets in the direction you want?

Comment: What are your netmasks? Have ypu checked if NAT/masquerading is disabled on tje routers?

Comment: @John I cant use LAN ports because with that I can't separate my networks, with many DHCPS in my network, the computer connect got the ip from the router that it wants, not the closest, or the router responsible for that pcs. I think managing with AD or other things is not what I want too, it doenst make things easy, because phones is allowed too

Comment: @DanielB we had I lot problem with networking in the past, the company is a hospital that takes a whole square of size, the routers crashed, and it was very difficult to discover where and why, separating those networks make things easy

Comment: @user1686 We have enterprises tp link too, six of nine is business routers like er605 tplink I asked about the mercusys one to see if its possible to make it work with these routers

Comment: @davidgo I will check it out, thanks